# Card layout not working with forms - Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to 2 forms, & I want to use card layout, so that when the user submits form1, he is taken to form2. But, when I try to `MyApp.container.setActiveItem(2)` (using console), it does not move to form2(card2).

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.Forms', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'formsPage',
    id: 'formsForm',

    config: {
        title: 'Patient Registration',
        iconCls: 'user',
        layout:{
            type: 'card'
        },

        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Patient Registration1',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Names',
                    name: 'name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'City',
                    name: 'city'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Patient Registration1',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Phone',
                    name: 'phone'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Country',
                    name: 'conutry'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],  
    constructor:function(config) {
            this.initConfig(config);
            return this;
        }

    }

});

MyApp.container = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Forms', {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that array items in Sencha Touch 2 are indexed from 0, so if you want to activate second one, it should be something like this:

`MyApp.container.setActiveItem(1)`

**Edited:** I've figured it out. You should add another config to your view: `fullscreen:true` and it should work well :)

Comment: I've figured it out. You should add another config to your view: `fullscreen:true` and it should work well :)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, this made setActiveItem(1) work. But, I have a tabpanel, in which this  MyApp.view.Forms is present (refer - http://pastebin.com/sCzunzWq). On setting fullscreen: true, the tabpanel is lost.

Comment: I'm not sure about your **homepanel** and **contactPage** definition but this code worked normally. Could you send me more details?
`Ext.application({
 name: 'MyApp',
 views: ['Forms'],
 launch: function(){
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'formsPage',
        }
    ]
});
}
})`

Comment: Please, find the homepanel & contactPage -
Home.js (homepanel) - http://pastebin.com/z1t1iSUw 
Contac.js (contactPage) - http://pastebin.com/vJhHE8DK

Comment: I've copied your code but could not find **productsPage** anywhere, so I assume it to be just like others, removing it from homepanel and see no errors. Everything works normally ...

Answer (score 0):

Is your form xtype of 'formsPage' custom, I can't seem to find it in the doco? If it's not, that might be contributing to the issue.

The doco also suggests that you don't create the card layout directly, but instead use carousel or tab panel. Maybe use a carousel as your base component, then make each card a separate form? This would make your intentions clear that each card/form is to be independent.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

do the following:
extend the carousel

1. extend: 'Ext.Carousel',

change the config section to:

1. config: {
       title: 'Patient Registration',
       iconCls: 'user',
       cls: 'card'
       ----

guess that should fix it

Comment: As per the documentation, I have been asked not to use carousel. Earlier, it was carousel & I have been assigned the task to change that.